# Tab jQuery "data-id" content

Tags: jquery, tabs

I wonder how I can make a call to a data-id in jQuery

For example:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="tab-menu">
    <li><a href="#item-1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-2">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-3">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-wrapper">
    <div class="tab-content" data-id="item-1">
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" data-id="item-2">
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" data-id="item-3">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".tab-menu a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

My level of jQuery is very basic, someone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(".tab-menu a").click(function(e) {  
    $("div [data-id]").hide(); // Hides all the elements with attribute data-id
    $("div [data-id='" + $(this).attr("href").replace("#","") + "']").show(); // display the div matching the selected li
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u6td2hom/2/

If you wish to use classes instead of hide/show :

```
$(".tab-menu a").click(function(e) {  
    $("div [data-id]").removeClass("active");  
    $("div [data-id='" + $(this).attr("href").replace("#","") + "']").addClass("active");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u6td2hom/3/

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "call to a data-id”? If you want to access its content:

`$("div").data("id")`

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/